# How to use multiple constructors using primary constructor feature in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class user with two fields string Name and int Age. I have a primary constructor as below:

```
public class User(string name, int age)
{
    public string Name { get; init; } = name;
    public int Age { get; init; } = age;
}
```

how to add one parameter constructor for field string Name and set value of age 18 as default?

I have tried adding another constructor like this:

```
public User(string name)
{
     Name = name;
     Age = 18;
}
```

but this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use overload of your constructor and call the primary constructor in your code. This is how you can do it:

```
public class User(string name, int age)
{
    public User(string name) : this(name, 18)
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; init; } = name;
    public int Age { get; init; } = age;
}
```

I hope this answer help you.

Answer (score 9):

You have to call the primary constructor from other constructors:

```
public User(string name) : this (name, 18) { }
```

This is covered in the 3rd paragraph of the documentation on [primary constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors#primary-constructors).